# Kubernetes heapster - Grafana doesn't display influxdb data

Tags: kubernetes

I deployed heapster with influxdb and grafana by following [heapster-influxDB guide](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fkubernetes%2Fheapster%2Fblob%2Fmaster%2Fdocs%2Finfluxdb.md&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNEoYG3zwdLq02lqnQanNidvqs9fww). When accessing the grafana instance I couldn't see any data in graphs(grafana service exposed to outside from NodePort). There are no errors in heapster and influxdb logs as attached below.

What could be the issue here? Really appreciate a positive feedback.

```
$ kubectl version
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"1", GitVersion:"v1.1.3", GitCommit:"6a81b50c7e97bbe0ade075de55ab4fa34f049dc2", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

Grafana dashboard

[image]

Grafana Datasource settings

[image]

heapster logs

```
I0510 10:33:12.556974       1 heapster.go:60] /heapster --source=kubernetes:https://kubernetes.default --sink=influxdb:http://monitoring-influxdb:8086
I0510 10:33:12.557111       1 heapster.go:61] Heapster version 1.1.0-beta1
I0510 10:33:12.557394       1 configs.go:60] Using Kubernetes client with master "https://kubernetes.default" and version "v1"
I0510 10:33:12.557414       1 configs.go:61] Using kubelet port 10255
I0510 10:33:12.619309       1 influxdb.go:199] created influxdb sink with options: host:monitoring-influxdb:8086 user:root db:k8s
I0510 10:33:12.619546       1 heapster.go:87] Starting with InfluxDB Sink
I0510 10:33:12.619601       1 heapster.go:87] Starting with Metric Sink
I0510 10:33:12.637683       1 heapster.go:166] Starting heapster on port 8082
I0510 10:33:35.000319       1 manager.go:79] Scraping metrics start: 2016-05-10 10:33:00 +0000 UTC, end: 2016-05-10 10:33:30 +0000 UTC
I0510 10:33:35.292539       1 manager.go:152] ScrapeMetrics: time: 292.067849ms size: 78
I0510 10:33:35.300239       1 influxdb.go:177] Created database "k8s" on influxDB server at "monitoring-influxdb:8086"

I0510 10:34:05.000270       1 manager.go:79] Scraping metrics start: 2016-05-10 10:33:30 +0000 UTC, end: 2016-05-10 10:34:00 +0000 UTC
I0510 10:34:05.274965       1 manager.go:152] ScrapeMetrics: time: 274.615057ms size: 78
I0510 10:34:35.000246       1 manager.go:79] Scraping metrics start: 2016-05-10 10:34:00 +0000 UTC, end: 2016-05-10 10:34:30 +0000 UTC
I0510 10:34:35.247562       1 manager.go:152] ScrapeMetrics: time: 247.236807ms size: 78
I0510 10:35:05.000265       1 manager.go:79] Scraping metrics start: 2016-05-10 10:34:30 +0000 UTC, end: 2016-05-10 10:35:00 +0000 UTC
```

Influxdb logs
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4f4RNm4mfqWZGtqbVBnWUJ2QjA

Refer the yaml files I used.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4f4RNm4mfqWY2pZRmViWHFuMFk

InfluxDB data
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4f4RNm4mfqWQTFxcFVhdko2Vms

Heapster api data
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4f4RNm4mfqWQVhEZ3oxdEs1VTA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens to be the Heapster master branch version is not compatible with some Kubernetes clusters. I tried following latest beta version and it works.

https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/releases/tag/v1.2.0-beta.0